# Asp.Net web forms log in schema - Keep a list of logged in users

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, request

i'm a beginner at developing a whole system so, need some approach guidance here folks. Hope you can help me! =)

In a try to create a log in schema, i have a Control class which keeps a list of logged users.

```
public static class ControleAcesso
{
    private static List<Associado> associadosLogados = new List<Associado>();
    public static Mensagens doLogin(Page pagina, String login, String senha)
    {
        Mensagens retorno = new Mensagens();
        retorno = AcessoDAL.Login(login, senha);

        if (retorno.Erros.Count() <= 0 && retorno.Objeto != null)
        {
            Associado assocLogado = new Associado();
            Associados assocEncontrado = (Associados)retorno.Objeto;

            assocLogado.ID = assocEncontrado.Associado;
            assocLogado.Nome = assocEncontrado.Nome;
            assocLogado.Nome_Fantasia = assocEncontrado.Nome_Fantasia;
            assocLogado.Data_Inclusao = assocEncontrado.Data_Inclusao;
            assocLogado.Email = assocEncontrado.Email;
            assocLogado.Data_Alteracao = assocEncontrado.Data_Alteracao;
            assocLogado.Login = assocEncontrado.Login;
            assocLogado.Senha = assocEncontrado.Senha;
            assocLogado.CGC_CPF = assocEncontrado.CGC_CPF;
            assocLogado.SessionID = pagina.Session.SessionID;

            var associadoJaLogado = associadosLogados.Where(x => x.ID == assocLogado.ID).FirstOrDefault();

            if (associadoJaLogado != null)
            {
                pagina.Session.Remove(associadoJaLogado.SessionID);
                associadosLogados.Remove(associadoJaLogado);
            }                
            associadosLogados.Add(assocLogado);
        }
        return retorno;
    }
}
```

So, this method basicaly do the login call to a Data Access Layer class. If the log in returns a user, i do Add this user to my list.

So, to later know my logged in users and retrieve data about then just using my session ID, i do some management in the list. Just the basic. Removing the logged in one and adding the new one.

The problem, as you probably noticed, is that, when i have two requests for the same credentials at the "same" time, it would allow the user to log in two times.

So, is this the best practice for log in schemes? Would you guys suggest me to change something?

I'm using ASP.NET Web Forms with C#.
Thank you in advice.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you explicitly want to force your users to use your application with one device at a time, you should not worry about the possibility that they might log in. So this is a problem if and only if it can violate one of your terms.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, thinking about this now, i think that's not a big problem. Do you see another problem? Or perhaps would propose another approach for a log in schema?

Comment: The only possible problem I see is that someone else might log in with the same credentials. You can prevent this by making sure that the identity of your users is protected by your system.

Comment: Actually, i'm handling with another problem, caused by this approach. When the user opens its browser, the SessionID sent is "exampleSessionID". Then, he logs in, and i save this sessionID with his log in details in a list of users. Ok. But then, he opens another tab in the browser and do the login again. The sessionID is still the same "exampleSessionID", so, the system will add this same session with the new user, and in a future request, i wont be able to determine whos requesting. im missing how to deal with SessionID to link with my user, once he is logged in. Thank you in advice.